# Field doesn't exist in destination table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a backup system that exports data from tables to .txt files for various reasons. I use a text stream object as I had problems with the usual export method truncating decimal places (this is a well known issue):

```
Sub ExportTables(fso As Object, exportPath As String, arr() As String)

Dim x As Integer
Dim recSet As Recordset
Dim fieldString As String
Dim fld As Variant
Dim txtStream As Object

For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
    
    fso.CreateTextFile exportPath & "\" & arr(x) & ".txt"
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(exportPath & "\" & arr(x) & ".txt", 8, Format:=TristateTrue)
    
    Set recSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(arr(x))
    With recSet
    
        fieldString = ""
        For Each fld In .fields
            fieldString = fieldString & "," & Chr(34) & fld.Name & Chr(34)
        Next fld
        fieldString = Right(fieldString, Len(fieldString) - 1)
        txtStream.WriteLine fieldString
    
        While Not .EOF
        
            fieldString = ""
            For Each fld In .fields
                If fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo Then
                    fieldString = fieldString & "," & Chr(34) & fld.value & Chr(34)
                Else
                    fieldString = fieldString & "," & fld.value
                End If
            Next fld
            
            fieldString = Right(fieldString, Len(fieldString) - 1)
            
            txtStream.WriteLine fieldString
        
            .movenext
        Wend
        
    End With
    
    txtStream.Close

Next x

End Sub
```

This works fine to create the file. However when I try to import these files I get an error:

> Field 'ÿþ' doesn't exist in destination table 'The_Table_In_Question.'

Using code:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, TableName:=arr(x), Filename:=fp & arr(x) & ".txt", HasFieldNames:=True
```

The same error happens regardless of which table, including the same strange field name 'ÿþ'.

I've uploaded a few of the back-up files to new tables via the external data dialogue and each import went without any problem and there were no unexpected fields.

I copy-pasted data from these backup files into new text files (literally select all, copy, paste) and they uploaded fine using the code above so I assume there is some kind of non-printable character weirdness going on with the text stream.

Comment: Your method goes severely wrong on OLE objects, attachments, multi-valued fields, text fields with quotes in them, and likely wrong on large number fields. Can you confirm none of these fields are in the table you're using it on?

Comment: @ErikA None of the above in any table. Its simple data, mostly small doubles, some strings but no quote marks. Largest number on one table only would be an integer with six digits.

Comment: How are you setting up the stream? Character encoding matters, this error could be explained by choosing the wrong encoding

Comment: @ErikA I've updated the post with the full method. `arr()` holds the table names

Comment: I assume you've either defined `TristateTrue` yourself, or are using a reference for it? As a general remark, I strongly recommend not using these libraries intended for VBS files, and instead either use native VBA code to work with files, or ADO stream objects.

Comment: @ErikA And there's me thinking I can get away without `Option Explicit`! Yes, it was that property defaulting to 0 because it was undeclared rather than -2 (use system default encoding). Thanks for spotting it.